# First Time Heroku Deploy App Can't Make Sense of Logs

Tags: heroku

This is my first time trying to deploy a small application on heroku to apply for an summer internship.

I went through the [getting started guide with rails.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)

Here is my log, its just too much code 
http://pastebin.com/QqaKVdH3

Is there something wrong with my rails app and not part of heroku?

Did I run out of dynos? I head into my apps, click on my app, and put in 2 dynos and 1 worker for my app.

I have this in my `procfile`, hopefully this is correct !

```
bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV 
bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

sorry to bother you guys, I know I need to familiarize myself with the heroku docs but if someone know the answer to this, I would love the help! I will just dig into the heroku docs when I got the time.

If you need more information please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error you should start with is this:

```
2013-05-13T19:35:12.367382+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2013-05-13T19:35:12.367055 #137] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant SimpleForm (NameError)
```

After you get past that hurdle and any others, be sure to checkout the Dev Center guide on Unicorn:

- [Deploying Rails Applications With Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn)